# Example of asymptotics for a discrete convolution

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, generating-functions, convolution, cauchy-product

I am interested in the technique that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127732/982564) refers to:

*Consider the generating functions $F(z) = \sum_n u_n z^n$ and $G(z) = \sum_n v_n z^n$.  The convolution has generating function $H(z) = F(z) G(z)$.  Assuming $u_n$ and $v_n$ grow at most exponentially, these series have nonzero radii of convergence, so $H$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$, and analysis of its closest singularities to 0 may be able to get you the leading terms in the asymptotics of your convolution.*

Could you show me how to work out a concrete example?

Comment: See [this paper](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/2009-SS/flajolet-odlyzko.pdf).